# Reopening recently closed instances of Excel

Tags: vba, excel

If I use the below code to close all instances of Excel that are currently open what would I need to use to reopen all the instances of Excel that were just closed?  I know I'll have to change the below to save a filepath somewhere but just not sure what the actual code should be.

```
Public Sub CloseAllExcel()
On Error GoTo handler

   Dim xl As Excel.Application
   Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

   Do While xl Is Nothing
      Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
      For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
         wb.Save
         wb.Close
      Next
      xl.Quit
      Set xl = Nothing
   Loop
   Exit Sub

handler:
   If Err <> 429 Then 'ActiveX component can't create object
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe construct an array which can hold the path of all the files before they are closed, write the array onto the sheet and next time when you open the macro workbook, you can open all the workbooks which you recently closed by reading the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stores file paths of the workbooks to a text file. If you run this macro with `False` as the input, this will open all of the recently closed files. (Not tested)

```
Public Sub CloseAllExcel(Closing As Boolean)
On Error GoTo handler

   Dim xl As Excel.Application
   Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

   Dim strPath As String
   strPath = "C:\path.txt"


   If Close Then

   Dim fso as Object
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   Dim oFile as Object
   Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strPath)



   Do While xl Is Nothing
      Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
      For Each wb In xl.Workbooks

       oFile.WriteLine Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 
         wb.Save
         wb.Close
      Next
       oFile.Close
       Set fso = Nothing
       Set oFile = Nothing
      xl.Quit
      Set xl = Nothing
   Loop

   Exit Sub

   Else
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim DataLine As String

   FileNum = FreeFile()
   Open strPath For Input As #FileNum

     While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine 
        Workbooks.Open DataLine
     Wend
   Exit Sub
   End If

handler:
   If Err <> 429 Then 'ActiveX component can't create object
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I am after I think, I just need to get it to work.  You can't use Close in the brackets declaring the sub's name (I'm not a VBA expert -  I don't actually know what those brackets are doing).  As this is a public sub I would have expected to be able to push F8 and cycle through the code but I can't do that - why is that?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @nick1408 That's an argument for the sub. you can call it through another sub or immediate window like this: CloseAllExcell True. Or you can remove the arguments inside the brackets and add Close = True (or False, if you want to open previously closed files) at the first line of the code.

Comment: Thanks again @Masoud.  When I put the code into the VBA editor the lines 

    public sub CloseAllExcel (Close As Boolean)
    If Close Then

cole up red (as in are no good).  The error given is a compile error Expected: identifier.  I'm having a crack at your suggested edits and will report back but I do like your original code option thought (CloseAllExcel True/False)

Comment: I think it was the name 'Close'.  Is it a reserved name?  Anyway, I changed it to Close1 and it fixed the red writing.  Also, I'm trying to get this to work from MS Access.  Do I need to set xl as Excel.Application?

Comment: @nick1408 I think so. Even if yiu don't need it is better to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Very-Hidden` worksheet, where you'll keep all of the Files currently open.

**Note**: If you want there is an option to Save and Read for the Registry.

**Sub *CloseAllExcel* Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CloseAllExcel()

On Error GoTo handler

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim Hidws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set Hidws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin")
On Error GoTo 0

If Hidws Is Nothing Then ' check if there isn't "Admin" sheet exists in the workbook
    Set Hidws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    Hidws.Name = "Admin"
    Hidws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden ' make the "Admin" sheet very-hidden
End If

i = 1
Do While xlApp Is Nothing
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
        Hidws.Range("A" & i).Value = wb.FullName ' save each workbook full name and path in column "A" in "Admin" very-hidden sheet
        i = i + 1
        wb.Close True
    Next
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
Loop
Exit Sub

handler:
If Err <> 429 Then 'ActiveX component can't create object
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

**Sub *RestoreExcelLastSession* Code**: reads the files (names and Path) from Column "A" in "Admin" very-hidden sheet.

```
Sub RestoreExcelLastSession()

Dim xlApp   As Excel.Application
Dim wb      As Excel.Workbook
Dim i       As Long
Dim Hidws   As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set Hidws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin")
On Error GoTo 0

If Hidws Is Nothing Then ' check if "Admin" sheet exists
    MsgBox "No Files have been restored"
    Exit Sub
End If

i = 1
Do While Hidws.Range("A" & i).Value <> ""  ' loop through cells in Column "A"
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' open a new Excel instance per file
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open (Hidws.Range("A" & i).Value)
    i = i + 1
    Set xlApp = Nothing
Loop

End Sub
```