# Make VBA run from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use a macro from MS Access that @masoud wrote for me here - [Reopening recently closed instances of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433124/reopening-recently-closed-instances-of-excel/43434009?noredirect=1#comment73980918_43434009)

What do I need to do to have it run from MS Access?  Code has been converted to the following to suit me:

```
Public Sub CloseAllExcel(Close1 As Boolean)
On Error GoTo handler

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

Dim strPath As String
strPath = "C:\path.txt"


If Close1 Then

Dim fso as Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim oFile as Object
Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strPath)



Do While xl Is Nothing
  Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  For Each wb In xl.Workbooks

   oFile.WriteLine Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 
     wb.Save
     wb.Close
  Next
   oFile.Close
   Set fso = Nothing
   Set oFile = Nothing
  xl.Quit
  Set xl = Nothing
Loop

Exit Sub

Else
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open strPath For Input As #FileNum

 While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine 
    Workbooks.Open DataLine
 Wend
 Exit Sub
 End If

 handler:
  If Err <> 429 Then 'ActiveX component can't create object
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

The issues I have is that oFile.WriteLine Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName  is having a method or data member not found for the ActiveWorkbook.  I'm a bit of a novice with this but I would have thought the code was good enough as is to work straight from MS Access.  It works if run from Excel though.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your context (running the code from Access), the Application object represent Access itself, not Excel, so it has no ActiveWorkbook object.  try changing `Application.ActiveWorkbook` to `xl.ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Spot on Vincent.  Thanks mate.